# Querying two tables using SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need help improving my SQLAlchemy query. I'm using Python 3.7, SQLAlchemy 1.3.15 and PosgresSQL 9.4.3 as database. I'm trying to return the count of appointments for a specific date and timeslot. However, my appointments and appointment slot tables are separate and I'm having to query both models/tables to get the desired results. Here's what I have;

**Appointments Model**

The appointment table have a few columns, which includes a foreign key to the appointment slots table.

```
class Appointment(ResourceMixin, db.Model): 
    __tablename__ = 'appointments'          

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'), index=True, nullable=True)
    slot_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('appointment_slots.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'), index=True, nullable=False)
    appointment_date = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False)
    appointment_type = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False, default='general')
```

**Appointment Slots Table**

The appointment slots table contains the time slots for the appointments. The Model consist of a relationship back to the appointments table.

```
class AppointmentSlot(ResourceMixin, db.Model):                                                   
    __tablename__ = 'appointment_slots'                                                           
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                                                                         
    # Relationships.                                                                              
    appointments = db.relationship('Appointment', uselist=False,                                  
                                   backref='appointments', lazy='joined', passive_deletes=True)   
    start_time = db.Column(db.String(5), nullable=False, server_default='08:00')                                                                                             
    end_time = db.Column(db.String(5), nullable=False, server_default='17:00')
```

**SQLAlchemy Query**

Currently I'm running the following SQLAlchemy query to get the appointment count for a specific date and time slot;

```
appointment_count = db.session.query(func.count(Appointment.id)).join(AppointmentSlot)\
        .filter(and_(Appointment.appointment_date == date, AppointmentSlot.id == Appointment.id,
                     AppointmentSlot.start_time == time)).scalar()
```

The query above return the correct results, which is a single digit value, but I'm worried that the query is not optimized. Currently the query returns in `380ms` , but there's only 8 records in the `appointments` and `appointment_slots` tables. These tables will eventually have in the 100s of thousands of records. I'm worried that even though the query is working now that it will eventually struggle with an increase of records.

How can I improved or optimized this query to improve performance? I was looking at SQLAlchemy subqueries using the appointment relationship on the `appointment_slots` table, but was unable to get it to work and confirm the performance. I'm thinking there must be a better way to run this query especially using the `appointments relationship` on the `appointment_slots` table, but I'm currently stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you enable debug logging or just `print(...)` the object before calling `scalar()`, it will show you the query it is calling. You can then inspect that to work out if you are performing an optimised query then check which columns you've indexed or not indexed then fix that.

Where are you getting the timing from - the database itself or on some other computer that is connecting to the database and running the python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrect about the query load time. I was actually looking at the page load that was 380ms. I also change the some fields on the models by removing the `slot_id` from the `appointments` model and adding a `appointment_id` foreign key to the `appointment_slots` model. The page load for the following query;

```
appointment_count = db.session.query(func.count(Appointment.id)).join(AppointmentSlot)\
        .filter(and_(Appointment.appointment_date == date, 
AppointmentSlot.appointment_id == Appointment.id, AppointmentSlot.start_time == time)).scalar()
```

ended up being; `0.4637ms`.

However, I still tried to improve the query and was able to do so by using a SQLAlchemy subquery. The following subquery;

```
subquery = db.session.query(Appointment.id).filter(Appointment.appointment_date == date).subquery()
query = db.session.query(func.count(AppointmentSlot.id))\
        .filter(and_(AppointmentSlot.appointment_id.in_(subquery),
 AppointmentSlot.start_time == time)).scalar()
```

Return a load time of `0.3700ms` which shows a much better performance than using the join query.